# ASP.NET: DataRow won't present content of database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, datarow

I want to present the content of the rows of my database in my website.
this is my code:

```
public partial class Movies : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string ConString = "Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Movie;Integrated Security=True";
    private SqlConnection Con ;
    private SqlCommand cmd ;
    private SqlDataAdapter adapter ;
    private string SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Movies";
    private DataTable dt;

    public DataTable DT
    {
        get { return dt ;}
        set { value = dt; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Session["UserEnter"] != null)
        {
            UserNameOrGuest.Text = Session["UserEnter"].ToString();
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        //}

        this.Con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        this.Con.Open();
        this.cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, Con);
        this.adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery,Con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);





    }
```

and this is My Webform :

```
  <%foreach (System.Data.DataRow dataRow in DT.Rows )
    {
        Label1.Text = DT.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString; 
    } %>
```

Why wont it present it properly ?

Thanks!

Comment: An aside, but get out of the habit of using "SELECT * from....." anything, never select *, be explicit in your data retrieval

Comment: I'm not sure that the thing, but in the DT property you wrote set { value = dt; } instead of set { dt = value ; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already looping through all the rows in your page, but you are assigning the **same value** (title from the first movie) to **the same label** (Label1).

Instead, using your foreach loop you would display the data for each row like this:

```
<% foreach (System.Data.DataRow dataRow in DT.Rows ) { %>
    <% = dataRow["Title"].ToString %>
    <br /> 
<% } %>
```

Notice that inside the loop you have access to each row individually. So just write out the value of the column(s) as you go.

Comment: Did you replace the "%<" at the end of the first line to "%>" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
 Label1.Text = dataRow["Title"].ToString;
```

That should work!

Comment: Yeah, tried that as well, and it says "cannot implicitly convert type object into a string...."

Comment: with the "ToString()" I dont get an error, though it just print "Label" .

Answer (score 0):

You are writing:
    dt = new DataTable();

Then in your page you have:

<%foreach (System.Data.DataRow dataRow in DT.Rows )

"DT" is your class, "dt" is what really contains the Datatable that you got. It should be:

<%foreach (System.Data.DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows ) // lower case dt